# Вызов метода вызывает ошибку линковщика

Tags: c++, c++11

Здравствуйте.

Есть метод:

```
bool m_containsIdentifier(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>&   vector, const std::string& identifier) {
    for (const auto& pair : vector) {
        if (pair.second == identifier) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Если я в коде пытаюсь его вызвать и скомпилировать этот код, то получаю  ошибку линковщика:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall SyntaxAnalyzer::m_containsIdentifier(class std::vector<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?m_containsIdentifier@SyntaxAnalyzer@@AAE_NABV?$vector@U?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@std@@@2@@std@@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)  C:\Users\devnikor\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SyntaxAnalyzer\SyntaxAnalyzer\SyntaxAnalyzer.obj
```

Сам вызов:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> identifiers = { };
std::string tokenBuf = "";
......
if (m_containsIdentifier(identifiers, tokenBuf))
    errors.push({ tokenBuf + " is already defined", m_lineNumber });
else
    identifiers.push_back({ tempType, tokenBuf });
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так это у Вас метод или функция? Потому что вызываете Вы функцию (разбираться с типами просто лениво)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `m_containsIdentifier` - это метод класса `SyntaxAnalyzer`, и он описан в cpp файле, то он должен быть описан как `bool SyntaxAnalyzer::m_containsIdentifier(параметры)`

Comment: Проглядел))

Спасибо